# How to change the scroll bar color in Firefox(Specific)?

Tags: css, firefox, scrollbar

I need to change the scroll bar color in Firefox. Using CSS I am able to change scroll bar color in IE. It works fine. But I cannot see the change in Firefox.

I dont want any custom scroll bars. I want to apply the color to the default scroll bar only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all browsers will let you control the styling for their scrollbars.

You can fake scroll bars with plugins like this, which claims to be cross-browser compatible:

http://www.kelvinluck.com/projects/jscrollpane-custom-cross-browser-scrollbars/

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this for the default scroll bar.

Use a custom scroll bar using javascript and CSS and lots of plugins will be available.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not doable without custom scroll bars.

Answer (score 0):

Using [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) will solve the scroll color cross browsers.

The usage is simple like: `$("#someDivId").jScrollPane();`
I tested under FireFox/IE/Chrome and got same UI result.

Also used [jScrollBar](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jscrollbar), but it require several divs before use jScrollBar, instead of one div.

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't without jQuery. Its because of bug #77790.

> Bug 77790 - (scrollbar-colors) Style the scrollbar (binding ::-moz-horizontal-scrollbar to XBL)

The only way is to use a jQuery plugin. I have links for you!
• http://plugins.jquery.com/custom-scrollbar/ - jQuery Custom Scrollbar
• http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/ - jScrollPane
• https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=jquery%20scrollbar - Google search

Answer (score -1):

for Firefox or cross browser you can use : 
 [jQuery custom content scroller](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/)

more simple and easy to use

Github : https://github.com/malihu/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin

How to use :
Download the source from the web or Github.

Include jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js and jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css on your header.

Add the class mCustomScrollbar to any element you want to add custom scrollbar(s) with default options. Example of mine : `<div class="long40 right reviews-frame mCustomScrollbar">`
Call mCustomScrollbar function on the element selector you want to add the scrollbar(s). I call in bottom of my phtml page (list.phtml) like this :

```
....    
</div>
<script>
(function($){
    $(window).load(function(){
        $(".content").mCustomScrollbar();
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Other setting and documentation you read on their web.

Sample I used it in Magento : i.imgur.com/3OwGQld.png

The following example of a scrollbar color css code that I modified :

```
#mCSB_1_dragger_vertical {
   height: 130px !important; /* height of the scrollbar */
}
.mCSB_dragger_bar {
   background-color: #ececec !important; /* color of the dragger bar */
}
.mCSB_scrollTools .mCSB_dragger .mCSB_dragger_bar {
   width: 10px !important; /* width of the dragger bar */
}
.mCSB_scrollTools .mCSB_draggerRail {
   background-color: #888888 !important; /* color of the rail */
   width: 10px !important; /* width of the rail for dragger bar */
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @LeftyX, I've added a brief explanation of its use. More details can be read on their website.And I've tried as compared to jScrollPane, use easier.